# Relationship with hybrid attribute as foreign key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use a hybrid attribute as a foreign key. In my `Transaction` class I have the following hybrid attribute:

```py
@hybrid_property
def target_id(self):
    return self.data_manual.target_id or self.data_inferred.target_id

@target_id.expression
def target_id(cls):
    coalesce(
        select([TransactionManual.target_id]).where(cls.id == TransactionManual.id).as_scalar(),
        select([TransactionInferred.target_id]).where(cls.id == TransactionInferred.id).as_scalar())
```

If the `transaction_id` is set automatically it is stored in `TransactionInferred`'s table, and if it is set manually by the user it is stored in `TransactionManual`'s table (`TransactionInferred` and `TransactionManual` have the same id as `Transaction`). The manual value overrides the automatic one.

#### How do would I then go about making a relationship?

I originally just had

```py
@property
def target():
    Target.query.filter(Target.id == self.target_id).first()
```

which works but I can't use it in queries.

I've tried

```py
target = db.relationship(Target, foreign_keys='Transaction.target_id', primaryjoin='Transaction.target_id == Target.id')
```

and dozens of variations of it, but none have worked. SQLAlchemy usually complains that there are no foreign keys linking the tables.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!